# Input tag with OnChange sometimes doesn't work, in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I have a function that renders in a component in react.

The function only appears when `props.teethData.data[1]["PDI"]` is true. I also have two input tags (one is type `number`, one is type `range`) they both change with the function `sliderValue` with an `onChange` event. it seems to be at random but sometimes the `setSliderP(value)` does not work and does not change the `value={sliderP}` in the input tags.

This is for a Teeth app, so when you change tooth teethData.data also changes. It tends to mostly happen when the props.teethData.data changes from one tooth to another and then back to the original tooth

Heres my code below

```
      function Pdindex()  {
        let number = 1
        if (props.teethData.data[1]["PDI"]) {  //Checks to see if ticked true 
          if (props.teethData.data[1]["PDI"][1] === undefined) { //if undefined -> because this first time setting value
            props.teethData.data[1]["PDI"] = [true, number] //make sure props are update
          } else {
            console.log('happened', props.teethData.data[1]["PDI"][1] ) //The value has been set before
            number = props.teethData.data[1]["PDI"][1] 
          }
        } else {
          console.log('this should happen when props.teethData.data[1]["PDI"] is not true')
        }
        var [sliderP, setSliderP] = useState(number)
        sliderP = number //for some reason it needs me to do this as useState(number) doesnt work
        function sliderValue(value) {
          sliderP = value
          props.teethData.data[1]["PDI"] = [true, value]
          setSliderP(value)
        }
        if (props.teethData.data[1]["PDI"]) {
          return (
            <>
              <div>
                <div className="spacing-30">
                  <input onChange={(event)=>sliderValue(event.target.value)} type='range' min="0" max="4" value={sliderP}/> 
                  <input type='number' min="0" max="4" className="slider-number" onChange={(event)=>sliderValue(event.target.value)} value={sliderP}/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </>
          )
        }
      }
```

Does anyone know why this could be?

Heres the full code, its quite large.

```
import PeriodPopUp from "../tooltips/periodPocketDepth";
import C14PopUp from "../tooltips/calculusIndex";
import GI03PopUp from "../tooltips/gingiv";
import GR14PopUp from "../tooltips/gingivRecession";
import PDIPopUp from "../tooltips/PDI";
import M03PopUp from "../tooltips/mobility";
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";


function PeriodontalDisplay(props) {

  console.log(props, 'period tooooooth table')



    const [PPDtrigger, SetPPDtrigger] = useState(false)
    function PPDtriggerPop(){
      SetPPDtrigger(!PPDtrigger) 
    }
  
    const [C14trigger, SetC14trigger] = useState(false)
    function C14triggerPop(){
      SetC14trigger(!C14trigger) 
    }
  
    const [GI03trigger, SetGI03trigger] = useState(false)
    function GI03triggerPop(){
      SetGI03trigger(!GI03trigger) 
    }
  
    const [GR14trigger, SetGR14trigger] = useState(false)
    function GR14triggerPop(){
      SetGR14trigger(!GR14trigger) 
    }
    const [PDItrigger, SetPDItrigger] = useState(false)
    function PDItriggerPop(){
      SetPDItrigger(!PDItrigger) 
    }
  
    const [M03trigger, SetM03trigger] = useState(false)
    function M03triggerPop(){
      SetM03trigger(!M03trigger) 
    }

    function Periodontalpocketdepth()  {


      
      let ppArray = {}
      if (props.teethData.data[1]["PP"].length > 1) {
        //console.log(props.teethData.data[1]["PP"], 'pp here values lets see')
        ppArray = {
          'aValue':props.teethData.data[1]["PP"][1]['aValue'],
          'bValue':props.teethData.data[1]["PP"][1]['bValue'],
          'cValue':props.teethData.data[1]["PP"][1]['cValue'],
          'dValue':props.teethData.data[1]["PP"][1]['dValue'],
          'eValue':props.teethData.data[1]["PP"][1]['eValue'],
          'fValue':props.teethData.data[1]["PP"][1]['fValue']
        }


      } else {
        //console.log('pp arent here',props.teethData.data)
        ppArray = {
          'aValue':0,
          'bValue':0,
          'cValue':0,
          'dValue':0,
          'eValue':0,
          'fValue':0
        }
        

      }

      const [aValue, setValue] = useState(ppArray)



      function sliderValue(value, type) {
        //console.log('call', value, type)
        if(type === 'aValue') {
          setValue((prevState) => {
            return { ...prevState, aValue: value };
          });
          props.teethData.data[1]["PP"] = [true, aValue]

        } else if (type === 'bValue') {
          setValue((prevState) => {
            return { ...prevState, bValue: value };
          });
          props.teethData.data[1]["PP"] = [true, aValue]

        } else if (type === 'cValue') {
          setValue((prevState) => {
            return { ...prevState, cValue: value };
          });
          props.teethData.data[1]["PP"] = [true, aValue]

        } else if (type === 'dValue') {
          setValue((prevState) => {
            return { ...prevState, dValue: value };
          });
          props.teethData.data[1]["PP"] = [true, aValue]

        } else if (type === 'eValue') {
          setValue((prevState) => {
            return { ...prevState, eValue: value };
          });
          props.teethData.data[1]["PP"] = [true, aValue]

        } else if (type === 'fValue') {
          setValue((prevState) => {
            return { ...prevState, fValue: value };
          });
          props.teethData.data[1]["PP"] = [true, aValue]
        } 

      }



      if (props.teethData.data[1]["PP"]) {
        return (
          <>
            <div>
              <div className="spacing-30">
                  <input type='number' className="input-pp" min="0" max="10" onChange={(event)=>sliderValue(event.target.value, 'aValue')} value={aValue.aValue}/>
                  <label className="label-white">A (Mesio-buccal)</label>
              </div>
              <div className="spacing-30">
                <input type='number' className="input-pp" min="0" max="10" onChange={(event)=>sliderValue(event.target.value, 'bValue')} value={aValue.bValue}/>
                <label className="label-white">B (Mesio-buccal)</label>
              </div>
              <div className="spacing-30">
                <input type='number' className="input-pp" min="0" max="10" onChange={(event)=>sliderValue(event.target.value, 'cValue')} value={aValue.cValue}/>
                <label className="label-white">C (Mesio-buccal)</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div className="spacing-30">
                <input type='number' className="input-pp" min="0" max="10" onChange={(event)=>sliderValue(event.target.value, 'dValue')} value={aValue.dValue}/>
                <label className="label-white">D (Mesio-palatal/lingual)</label>
              </div>
              <div className="spacing-30">
                <input type='number' className="input-pp" min="0" max="10" onChange={(event)=>sliderValue(event.target.value, 'eValue')} value={aValue.eValue}/>
                <label className="label-white">E (Palatal/lingual)</label>
              </div>
              <div className="spacing-30">
                <input type='number' className="input-pp" min="0" max="10" onChange={(event)=>sliderValue(event.target.value, 'fValue')} value={aValue.fValue}/>
                <label className="label-white">F (Disto-palatal/lingual)</label>
              </div>
            </div>
  
          </>
        )
      }
      }

      function CalculusIndex()  {
        let number = 0
        if (props.teethData.data[1]["C14"].length>1) {
          number = props.teethData.data[1]["C14"][1]
        } else {
          number = 0
        }
        const [slider, setSlider] = useState(number)
        
        function sliderValue(value) {
          props.teethData.data[1]["C14"] = [true, value]
          setSlider(value)

        }
        if (props.teethData.data[1]["C14"]) {
          return (
            <>
              <div>
                <div className="spacing-30">
                  
                  <input onChange={(event)=>sliderValue(event.target.value)} type='range' min="1" max="4" value={slider}/> 
                  <input type='number' className="slider-number" onChange={(event)=>sliderValue(event.target.value)} value={slider}/>

                  </div>
              </div>
            </>
          )
        }
      }

      function GingIndex()  {
        let number = 0
        if (props.teethData.data[1]["GI0"]) {  //Checks to see if ticked true
          if (props.teethData.data[1]["GI0"][1] === undefined) { //if undefined -> because this first time setting value
            props.teethData.data[1]["GI0"] = [true, number] //make sure props are update
          } else {
            number = props.teethData.data[1]["GI0"][1] 
          }
        } 
        var [slider, setSlider] = useState(number)
        slider = number
        function sliderValue(value) {
          slider = value
          props.teethData.data[1]["GI0"] = [true, value]
          setSlider(value)
        }

        if (props.teethData.data[1]["GI0"]) {
          return (
            <>
              <div>
                <div className="spacing-30">
                  <input onChange={(event)=>sliderValue(event.target.value)} type='range' min="0" max="3" value={slider}/> 
                  <input type='number' min="0" max="3" className="slider-number" onChange={(event)=>sliderValue(event.target.value)} value={slider}/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </>
          )
        }
      }

      function GingRecess()  {
        let number = 0
        if (props.teethData.data[1]["GR"]) {  //Checks to see if ticked true
          if (props.teethData.data[1]["GR"][1] === undefined) { //if undefined -> because this first time setting value
            number = 1
            props.teethData.data[1]["GR"] = [true, number] //make sure props are update
          } else {
            number = props.teethData.data[1]["GR"][1] 
          }
        } 
        var [slider, setSlider] = useState(number)
        slider = number
        
        function sliderValue(value) {
          props.teethData.data[1]["GR"] = [true, value]
          setSlider(value)
        }
        if (props.teethData.data[1]["GR"]) {
          return (
            <>
              <div>
                <div className="spacing-30">
                  <input onChange={(event)=>sliderValue(event.target.value)} type='range' min="1" max="4" value={slider}/> 
                  <input type='number' className="slider-number" onChange={(event)=>sliderValue(event.target.value)} value={slider}/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </>
          )
        }
      }

      function Pdindex()  {
        let number = 1
        if (props.teethData.data[1]["PDI"]) {  //Checks to see if ticked true 
          if (props.teethData.data[1]["PDI"][1] === undefined) { //if undefined -> because this first time setting value
            props.teethData.data[1]["PDI"] = [true, number] //make sure props are update
          } else {
            console.log('happened', props.teethData.data[1]["PDI"][1] ) //The value has been set before
            number = props.teethData.data[1]["PDI"][1] 
          }
        } else {
          console.log('this should happen when props.teethData.data[1]["PDI"] is not true')
        }
        var [sliderP, setSliderP] = useState(number)
        sliderP = number //for some reason it needs me to do this as useState(number) doesnt work
        function sliderValue(value) {
          sliderP = value
          props.teethData.data[1]["PDI"] = [true, value]
          setSliderP(value)
        }
        if (props.teethData.data[1]["PDI"]) {
          return (
            <>
              <div>
                <div className="spacing-30">
                  <input onChange={(event)=>sliderValue(event.target.value)} type='range' min="0" max="4" value={sliderP}/> 
                  <input type='number' min="0" max="4" className="slider-number" onChange={(event)=>sliderValue(event.target.value)} value={sliderP}/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </>
          )
        }
      }

      function Mob()  {
        let number = 0
        if (props.teethData.data[1]["M03"].length>1) {
          number = props.teethData.data[1]["M03"][1]
        } else {
          number = 0
        }
        const [slider, setSlider] = useState(number)
        function sliderValue(value) {
          props.teethData.data[1]["M03"] = [true, value]
          setSlider(value)

        }
        if (props.teethData.data[1]["M03"]) {
          return (
            <>
              <div>
                <div className="spacing-30">
                  <input onChange={(event)=>sliderValue(event.target.value)} type='range' min="0" max="3" value={slider}/> 
                  <input type='number' className="slider-number" onChange={(event)=>sliderValue(event.target.value)} value={slider}/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </>
          )
        }
      }






    return (
      <div className="period-table">

        <div className="period-table-sec">

          <input
            className="check-box"
            type="checkbox"
            id="pp"
            onChange={() => props.onToothCondition(1, "PP")}
            checked={props.teethData.data[1]["PP"]}
          />
          <label className="text-check-box" id="PP">
            <dt>PP #</dt> Periodontal pocket depth <button className="questionButton"  onClick={() => SetPPDtrigger(!PPDtrigger)}> ?  </button>
            
            <PeriodPopUp trigger={PPDtrigger}  onTrigger={PPDtriggerPop} animalType={props.animalType}> </PeriodPopUp>
          </label>
          <div className="right-table">
            {Periodontalpocketdepth()}
          </div>    
        </div>


        <div className="wrapper-table">

          <div className="first-table">
            <input
              className="check-box"
              type="checkbox"
              id="C14"
              checked={props.teethData.data[1]["C14"]}
              onChange={() => props.onToothCondition(1, "C14")}
            />
            <label className="text-check-box" id="C14">
              <dt>C 1-4</dt> calculus index <button className="questionButton" onClick={() => SetC14trigger(!C14trigger)}> ?  </button>
              <C14PopUp trigger={C14trigger}  onTrigger={C14triggerPop} animalType={props.animalType}></C14PopUp>
            </label>
            <div className="right-pp">
              {CalculusIndex()}
            </div>
          </div>




          <div className="second-table">
            <input
              className="check-box"
              type="checkbox"
              id="GI0"
              onChange={() => props.onToothCondition(1, "GI0")}
              checked={props.teethData.data[1]["GI0"]}
            />
            <label className="text-check-box" id="GI0">
              <dt>GI 0-3</dt> gingivitis index <button className="questionButton" onClick={() => SetGI03trigger(!GI03trigger)}> ?  </button>
              <GI03PopUp trigger={GI03trigger}  onTrigger={GI03triggerPop} animalType={props.animalType}></GI03PopUp>
            </label>
            <div className="right-pp">
              {GingIndex()}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="wrapper-table">
          <div className="first-table">
            <input
              className="check-box"
              type="checkbox"
              id="GI23"
              onChange={() => props.onToothCondition(1, "GI23")}
              checked={props.teethData.data[1]["GI23"]}
            />
            <label className="text-check-box" id="GI">
              <dt> GI 2/3</dt> Bleeding when probing 
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className="second-table">
            <input
              className="check-box"
              type="checkbox"
              id="GR"
              onChange={() => props.onToothCondition(1, "GR")}
              checked={props.teethData.data[1]["GR"]}
            />
            <label className="text-check-box" id="GR">
              <dt>GR 1-4</dt> gingival recession <button className="questionButton" onClick={() => SetGR14trigger(!GR14trigger)}> ?  </button>
              <GR14PopUp trigger={GR14trigger}  onTrigger={GR14triggerPop} animalType={props.animalType}></GR14PopUp>
            </label>
            <div className="right-pp">
              {GingRecess()}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="wrapper-table">
          <div className="first-table">
            <input
              className="check-box"
              type="checkbox"
              id="PDI"
              onChange={() => props.onToothCondition(1, "PDI")}
              checked={props.teethData.data[1]["PDI"]}
            />
            <label className="text-check-box" id="PDI">
              <dt>PDI/ 0-4 </dt>periodontal disease index  <button className="questionButton" onClick={() => SetPDItrigger(!PDItrigger)}> ?  </button>
              <PDIPopUp trigger={PDItrigger}  onTrigger={PDItriggerPop} animalType={props.animalType}></PDIPopUp>
              

            </label>
            <div className="right-pp">
              {Pdindex()}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="second-table">
            <input
              className="check-box"
              type="checkbox"
              id="M03"
              onChange={() => props.onToothCondition(1, "M03")}
              checked={props.teethData.data[1]["M03"]}
            />
            <label className="text-check-box" id="M03">
              <dt>M 0-3</dt> mobility  <button className="questionButton"  onClick={() => SetM03trigger(!M03trigger)}> ?  </button>
              <M03PopUp trigger={M03trigger}  onTrigger={M03triggerPop} animalType={props.animalType}> </M03PopUp>
            </label>
            <div className="right-pp">
              {Mob()}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="wrapper-table">
          <div className="first-table">
            <input
              className="check-box"
              type="checkbox"
              id="furcation"
              onChange={() => props.onToothCondition(1, "F13")}
              checked={props.teethData.data[1]["F13"]}
            />
            <label className="text-check-box" id="furcation">
              <dt> F 1-3 </dt>furcation <button className="questionButton"> ?  </button>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  export default PeriodontalDisplay;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think the biggest issue here is having `var [sliderP, setSliderP] = useState(number)` inside the function.

When React re-renders your component frequently, they're going to retrigger the `Pdindex()` function. Because you've put the state inside that function, you actually lose state and the `setSliderP`/`sliderP` won't work.

The state is only stored between renders for actual components. Pdindex is not a component, just a function that returns something. Its usage of "useState" is gone after the next rerender.

You have 2 options:

**1. Make `PdIndex()` an actual component so that its own state persists between renders**
Make Pdindex a functional component with the necessary props and use it as `<Pdindex ... />`

**2. (simpler but I'd recommend the above still) Move the `[sliderP, setSliderP] = useState(number)` outside of the function**. All state should be defined toplevel within the react component itself, not within subfunctions.

Comment: Thank you thats some really helpful advice! Im a self taught react user, so i always question if how i am actually doing something is the correct way

Comment: While there's no hard rule/way to organize your component, it's not a bad idea to try to keep your components isolated to a general specific purposes (i.e. aim for smaller functional components). So a bunch of the other functions you have in their that also return JSX, you could conver them to other components in their own files. This way it also makes it easier for you to work in different components and code while making your own code more readable and easier to sift through.

Comment: When i do Option 2, i get an error `react-dom.development.js:14997 Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.` how can i fix this

Comment: If you're using your `sliderValue` function as is, you'll need to refactor that out into a top level function as well

Comment: That's setting the state and triggering rerenders as well